# i get undefined for first value in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make loop through an element the have unique `id`
but the first  value in the for returns `undefined` please help

```
function load_like(){
  var value='';
  $(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        value = $('#like_check_'+i).attr('data-id');
        alert(value);
    }
  }
 }
```

this is the html to loop through

```
<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_0" title="I like it"></i>
<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_1" title="I like it"></i>
<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_2" title="I like it"></i>
<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_3" title="I like it"></i>
<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_4" title="I like it"></i>
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example and it worked for me. Only the forth value was undefined, but that's because there is no `like_check_3` in your html

Comment: @JoseNuno it is still showing undefined for i = 0

Comment: Do you have other elements in your html with the same id? (e.g. like_check_0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `like_check_` starts from 0 to 4 to it skips number 3 hence why you see undefined change it to `like_check_3`

```js
function load_like(){
  var value='';
  $(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        value = $('#like_check_'+i).attr('data-id');
        console.log(value);
    }
  })
 }

load_like()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_0" title="I like it"></i>

<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_1" title="I like it"></i>

<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_2" title="I like it"></i>

<i class="fas fa-heart float-right p-1 my-1 mr-3" data-id="1" id="like_check_3" title="I like it"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you get undefined once because you are missing

```
id="like_check_3"
```